# "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list". The primary key does exist though

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

So i'm practicing some sql coding for a test and I can't get a foreign key to reference a primary key.

Here's the table that doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENT(
ASSIGN_ID NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
START_DATE DATE,
END_DATE DATE,
BUDGET NUMBER (10,2),
MANAGER_ID NUMBER(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (ASSIGN_ID,MANAGER_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID)
);
```

Here's the table it is referencing:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
EMP_ID NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR(40),
OFFICE VARCHAR(20),
EXPERT_ID NUMBER(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID,EXPERT_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (EXPERT_ID) REFERENCES EXPERTISE(EXPERT_ID)
);
```

Whenever I try to run the script it always comes back with:

> Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
>   02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
>   *Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
>              gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
>              key constraint in the referenced table.
>   *Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
>              catalog view

I've looked around but can't seem to find the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the full code (haven't tested the last table yet):

```
CREATE TABLE EXPERTISE(
EXPERT_ID NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50),
HOURLY_RATE NUMBER(3,2),
CHARGE_RATE NUMBER(3,2),
  PRIMARY KEY(EXPERT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
EMP_ID NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR(40),
OFFICE VARCHAR(20),
EXPERT_ID NUMBER(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID,EXPERT_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (EXPERT_ID) REFERENCES EXPERTISE(EXPERT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENT(
ASSIGN_ID NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
START_DATE DATE,
END_DATE DATE,
BUDGET NUMBER (10,2),
MANAGER_ID NUMBER(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (ASSIGN_ID,MANAGER_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE ALLOCATION(
EMP_ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
ASSIGN_ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
DAYS_WORKED_ON DATE,
HOURS_WORKED_ON DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY(EMP_ID,ASSIGN_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(EMP_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(ASSIGN_ID) REFERENCES ASSIGNMENT(ASSIGN_ID)
);
```

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to make it

Comment: Your life will be a whole lot simpler if you use surrogate keys plus unique indexes for those keys pairs

Comment: Um.   Those are surrogate keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Cause: A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary key
>   constraint in the referenced table.

The problem is that `EMP_ID` (by itself) isn't a primary or unique key of table `Employees`, instead, you have a compound primary key `(EMP_ID, EXPERT_ID)`.

To fix the issue either make `EMP_ID` the primary key of the `Employees` table (which seems intuitive as each employee ought to have a unique id) or add a separate unique constraint on `EMP_ID`.

As pointed out in the comments, if you make `EMP_ID` the primary key, then  `(EMP_ID, EXPERT_ID)` will also be unique by extension.

Comment: If emp_id is made into the primary key, a unique constraint on emp_id, expert_id would be redundant - emp_id would already be unique by itself.

Comment: Just took expert_id out of primary key in the employee table and that fixed it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggest, the column you've referenced a foreign key doesn't match a unique constraint/pk on the parent table. Specifically for the primary key EMP_ID, EXPERT_ID you reference only EMP_ID.